# Django: How to drop a proxy model and convert its values to super-type

Tags: django

I am using proxy models in django, like this:

```
class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Now I want to delete the B model, and convert its values (table rows) to type A.
Since proxy models use the same table as its parent, and there is no extra fields in my proxy model, it should not be necessary to touch the model table itself.

I have deleted the model (code) and removed the respective row from `django_content_type`, but django must store info somewhere else about which row is of which type, A or B. The rows inserted as B type, still doesn't show up as A type.

I am using south. The *best* solution would be to add this as an migration, but not strictly necessary.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything other than remove the content type. [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) aren't represented separately in the database at all (other than in content types). Proxy models are basically just helpers for doing things like adding a different default manager, changing ordering, etc.

You can also run `django-admin.py schemamigration <appname> --auto` to verify that there aren't any changes (South doesn't even consider Proxy models when making migrations).

Comment: Yes, as I said: "I have deleted the model (code) and removed the respective row from django_content_type, but django must store info somewhere else about which row is of which type, A or B."

Comment: @RoarSkullestad no, as I've stated, a proxy model isn't represented as different in the database. It's there in your code for your own use, and you can certainly add a field to the parent model. For example, you have a `Animal` model and a `Lion` proxy model, and you add an `is_lion` boolean field to the `Animal` model. That's a common use case for proxy models, but you don't have to use proxy models that way, and there aren't any extra feilds added by Django.

Comment: From my question: "Since proxy models use the same table as its parent..." The source of the confusion was that I had myself extended the proxy mechanism so that the A model did not return rows inserted via the B model... :)